# Applying Linear Impulse on dynamic body

Tags: box2d

I am new to Box 2D and trying to solve a problem. I have a dynamic body and it is placed at the center of the screen. And I am applting linear impluse on the body when the screen is touched any where by the user, but I am unable to get the desired result. I want the impulse to applied to the direction where user have touched.

Please find the code below.

```
striker.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()), striker.getPosition());
```

I want the body to go where the user have touched on the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code that will help you:

```
dir = touchPos - bodyCenterPos
dir.normalize()
impulse = dir * IMPULSE_FORCE
applyImpulse()
```